# Can or why can't I search for element by index in std::set?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, std

There are a couple questions on this site about accessing elements in a `std::set` by index, but the answers I saw were old and unenlightening.

Ordered sets can be (and often are) implemented as binary search trees.  In a binary search tree, by storing the number of nodes in the tree rooted at each node, we can access the `k`th element in sorted order in `O(log n)` time without increasing the algorithmic complexity of other operations (please correct me if this is the error in my thinking).

Nevertheless, if I want the `k`th element in sorted order from a `set::set`, I must walk from `begin()` all the way to k, using `O(k)` time instead.  In general, this may equate to `O(n)` time.

So, my questions are:

- Is it correct that we could maintain a height-balanced binary search tree in which it's possible to find the `k`th element in `O(log n)` time without damaging the time complexity of other operations?
- If so, is there a function or alternate data structure in the C++ standard library which I could utilize to this effect?
- If yes to the former but no to the latter, has it been or is it being considered? Is it not implemented because of some technical barrier or simply because the implementation cost is deemed too expensive for the potential utility of this feature?

Comment: How would you expect a node on a tree to know the count of nodes in its children? The C++ standard puts many constraints on implementations by specifying the timing of many operations.

Comment: For all insert/remove operations you'd need to walk from or to the root to update. This isn't necessarily a bad thing as you need to walk most of the time anyway for those operations. It'd mean some more overhead per node but that wouldn't change complexity. Something like `std::set::insert(hint, ...);` wouldn't work as that forces amortised constant which isn't possible if you must walk. But that function is a bit of a corner case. So Yes (with above caveat). No, Never Heard of it.

Comment: Note the Standard doesn't say anything at all about implementing via binary trees. It's just that the complexity requirements for the ordered associative containers make trees a natural choice.

Comment: @aschepler the standard doesn't say anything about implementations, but an implementation is always assumed when the rules are drawn up. I believe it's not just any binary tree but a specific type that's needed to make a conforming implementation, but I don't remember the details.

Comment: I had a further thought about this. If you are not doing insertions on the set very often, you can replace it with a sorted vector and use `std::lower_bound` or `upper_bound` for lookup and insertion.

Answer (score 5):

It *is* possible to augment a (balanced) search tree with extra information that can be used to implement searching by index in logarithmic time. Such augmented search tree may be called an [order statistic tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree).

Augmenting the tree doesn't affect the worst case asymptotic complexity of the main operations (insert, lookup, erase): Their worst case is still logarithmic. I don't know whether it prevents amortized constant complexity that is required for erase and hinted insertion operations of the ordered associative containers.

Asymptotic complexity is not the only criteria for a feature however. Augmenting the tree increases the complexity coefficient of the logarithmic operations making all (or most) other operations slower. It also increases the spatial overhead of the data structure. So, just because such data structure is possible, doesn't necessarily mean it would be good idea to use it to implement the generic associative containers provided by the standard library.

No. There is no container based on a search tree with logarithmic index lookup in the standard library.

I found a proposal [n3700](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3700.html#tree.tree.adaptors.augment.general) based on the Boost tree component library which proposes to add generic tree structures. It includes the class `rank_tree`, which appears to be an augmented search tree that provides the operation that you are looking for.

Comment: Wonderful, nice to know people have studied it and the theory works.  Downside is that's a rather complicated data structure to re-engineer for its relatively niche applicability.

Comment: And just to add, to cover the OP's third query, that this is not the intended use for a set. It is not provided to be "a tree", but to be "a bag of objects", and though (in contrast to an unordered_set) they are guaranteed to be in an order so as to aid with various algorithms and whatnot, we're not really supposed to care about that in the sense of treating it as a sequence (because it's not a sequence). This may sound academic but it's precisely what drives the feature set design of the container. This fits into what aschepler commented also.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I appreciate the comment, but that only addresses `std::set`, leaving the question regarding adding an alternate data structure for this purpose (the order statistic tree mentioned by eerorika) still open.  Also, a side question: if a container provides me with a forward iterator, thus allowing me to walk through all the elements in a specific deterministic order, how is this not a sequence?

Comment: @Apollys Your third query specifically asked about `std::set` in cases where a hypothetical alternative doesn't exist, so that's what I talked about. As for your follow-up, yes forward iterators are provided, but this is a bit of an abstraction leak; the language emphatically does not consider a set to be a sequence container.

Comment: The third question is asking why the alternative (appropriate) data structure has not been implemented in the C++ standard library.  I see now the antecedent of "it" may be unclear, my intention was to refer to the function or alternate data structure mentioned immediately preceding.